# git push error with SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I use SourceTree to commit my code and when push code to remote with terminal, it encountered an error:

```
lushumingdeMacBook-Pro:xk-control lucien$ git push
Password authentication
Password:
Password:
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
  $ git config 'lfs.https://192.168.1.117/xk-control.git/info/lfs.locksverify' false
Password:
Password:
^CKilled by signal 2.
```

So I type in
`git config 'lfs.https://192.168.1.117/xk-control.git/info/lfs.locksverify' false`

But it doesn't work.
The git server is based on Gitblit.
I guess SourceTree add some configs about LFS on repo by default.
Hopes some one could help me.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I also typed the suggested command. Afterwards it still gave the same error.